# How to upgrade to 10.13.3 with fusion drive on apfs

Tags: macos, upgrade, high-sierra, fusion-drive, apfs

I installed High Sierra via the app store, the regular way. In the process the fusion drive of my mac mini was converted to apfs.

I am still on 10.13.1, and wondered, why available upgrades did not show up, so I downloaded

- macOSUpd10.13.2Supplemental.dmg
- macOSUpd10.13.3.dmg

from the apple website. When I try to install them, I cannot chose any of my drives and the dialog dispays this link for further explaination:

https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/apfsfusion

Which states, that I installed apfs during the High Sierra Beta program, which converted my fusion drive to apfs, which somehow seems not to have been the right thing to do and now I would have to backup, setup newly and restore my whole system, something that would take me days to complete.

The thing is, I never signed up any apple beta program and I am unsure whether I am seeing this notification, because I try to install the upgrades from downloaded disk images and have not waited enough for the upgrade to apear by itself. On the other hand I am already missing out on the second iteration of High Sierra and this makes me uneasy, too.

Could anyone clarify my situation for me?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you just have to threaten your mac here on askdifferent. Then, it will just install the 10.13.3 update overnight.

:P